# Whats wrong with the syntax here ? It says The server tag is not well formed

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
Visible='<%# ((Eval('<%# Eval("IsDefault")%>'))="True" ? Eval("False") : Eval("True") )%>'>>
```

Comment: You can't have "nested Eval" as far as I know. use the ItemDataBound event and set the Visible in code behind instead, as Nick suggested..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** Given that IsDefault is True in the database you can do this by defining a helper function in your code behind:

```
// in codebehind
public string GetIsVisible(bool isDefault)
{
    return (isDefault) ? "false" : "true";
}

// in web form...
Visible='<%# GetIsVisible(DataBinder.Eval("IsDefault")) %>'
```

Comment: if IsDefault in DB is true then what does True!=True evaluate to ? I am confused

Comment: Where x = true, (x != true) would evaluate to false. Although that's irrelevant now that you have clarified that by "True" in your question you actually meant a boolean rather than a string.

Answer (score 6):

You just want a bool here, the nested quotes are what is giving you issues, try this instead:

```
Visible='<%# Eval("IsDefault") == "True"  %>'
```

Though, depending on where you're using this, it may not be allowed either way.  For example in a server tag you'll get something along the lines of "Cannot convert `"<%# Eval("IsDefault") == "True"  %>"` to a boolean."

Comment: I want the control to display based in IsDefault's value..Link button will be made visible if IsDEfault is not true

Comment: @Serenity - does it have an ID, it seems like you'd want to do this from the code-behind in most cases (given the restrictions on tag syntax here)

Answer (score 3):

Your quotes are not balanced: `'<%# ((Eval('`